# Laravel get unique id when sending emails with Mailgun

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

i took a look at mailguns api and whenever they send a webhook they send also this id:

```
"id": "-laxIqj9QWubsjY_3pTq_g",
```

This is i guess their unique id for every email. Is there any way to get id when sending emails so i can track for which email i received webhook ? I can't only search by the recipient email, i need some unique id. This is how i send emails:

```
 Mail::send('email.subscription', $data, function ($message) use ($email) 
 {
     $message->to($email)->subject('Welcome')->from('no-reply@name.com', 'My Name');
 });
```

Comment: You are talking about webhooks, so when you send email using API the API does its job and also sends a webhook at pre-configured URL with POST data, so what you need is to create endpoint on your side to fetch this data and process it. Go through Mailgun API reference it should be all there (I haven't read it so I may be mistaken, I just taken as fact that you are talking about **webhooks**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own unique ID on sending (DB auto-increment ID or GUID perhaps).

Then you can use the "attach data to messages" feature to add that unique ID when sending the email. https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages

It sends that data back in the webhook.  See "Custom Variables" in the tracking "opens" webhook: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tracking-opens